# regular expression in Js for Decimal Format (123,456.789 and 123.456,789)

Tags: javascript, regex

i need the regular expression for my input-pattern for 2 of this Decimal Format:

`123,456.789` and `123.456,789`

```
DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP: new RegExp('^[+-]?(?=.)(?:\\d+\\.)?\\d+(?:,\\d+)?$')
DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP: new RegExp('^[+-]?(?=.)(?:\\d+,)?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$')
```

if i give this input: 1.000.000,123 don't accept it. why and what is the why to define the regular expression?

Comment: Which part of your regular expression allows multiple instances of `.` or `,`?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want three number separated by exactly one comma and exactly one decimal point?

Comment: `([+-]?(?:(?:\d+,\d+.\d+)|(?:\d+.\d+,\d+)))` You might have to play with the capture groups.  This currently captures the whole string

Comment: Be more specific about the format. Do you want each delimiter between the digits to be a comma OR decimal, or must it only be one comma and one decimal in the string but order doesn't matter - tl;dr, are `123.456.789` and `123,456,789` also accepted.

Answer (score 1):

These two should do it:

```
DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP: new RegExp('^[+-]?\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*(,\\d+)?$')
DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP: new RegExp('^[+-]?\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?$')
```

Working example:

```js
a = '123,456.789'
b = '123.456,789'
c = '1.11111'
d = '12.21'
e = '1,11111'
f = '12,21'
g = '12345.1'
h = '12345,1'

DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP = new RegExp('^[+-]?\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*(,\\d+)?$')
DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP = new RegExp('^[+-]?\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?$')

console.log('COMMA TESTS:')
console.log(a, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(a))
console.log(b, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(b))
console.log(c, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(c))
console.log(d, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(d))
console.log(e, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(e))
console.log(f, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(f))
console.log(g, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(g))
console.log(h, DECIMAL_COMMA_REGEXP.test(h))

console.log('')

console.log('POINT TESTS:')
console.log(a, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(a))
console.log(b, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(b))
console.log(c, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(c))
console.log(d, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(d))
console.log(e, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(e))
console.log(f, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(f))
console.log(g, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(g))
console.log(h, DECIMAL_POINT_REGEXP.test(h))
```

The way these work is:

1. Any digit 1 to 3 times (1 10 100)
2. Same as (1), but preceded by a `,`. Zero or more times (,999,999…)
3. Any number of decimal digits or none (.123456)

Comma decimals: https://regex101.com/r/PnfUiL/1
Point decimals: https://regex101.com/r/PnfUiL/2

Comment: `11.13,1234` will pass your test (which I guess shouldn't...)

Comment: @Dekel Really? Could you please post a proof somewhere? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: wrong check, but you have some other problem there...  check this: https://jsfiddle.net/obnpjd0s/

Comment: Add a snippet with console.log, it will be much easier to verify.

Comment: Well spotted, thank you @Dekel. I forgot that `new RegExp()` needs double-escaping of backslashes as opposed to `/literals/`

Comment: Better now :) also - I added a snippet to your answer. Much easier to test.